# what is this error Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by that i get when i query my rest web-service built with php

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP error: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793482/php-error-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent)

I've built a web-service with framework CakePHP. when i query the service it does return the expected content but, it also gives me an error: Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by. What is this and how can i resolve this?

Comment: BTW, a small tip, remove the ending `?>` from your pure php files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be that you try to set headers using [header](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function after some of the content is already sent.