# Log in form on the top right headers content

Tags: php, html, css

i made a log in form in header on the top right side with the other contents like search bar and logo

and i have a plan when i logged in the other headers content is stand still but only the log in content is changing to the Logged in content

and here is my code that i assume have no problem at all

PHP code

```
if(empty($_POST) === false){
$username = $_POST['input-username'];
$password = $_POST['input-password'];

    if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) ===true){
        $errors[] = 'You Need To Enter a Username And a Password';
        }
        else if(user_exists($username) === false){
        $errors[] = 'We Can\'t Find That Username';
            }

        else{
            $login = login($username, $password);

                if($login === false){
                    $errors[] = 'Your Username and Password Combination is Incorrect';
                    }
                else{
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
                    header("Location: index.php");
                    }
            }
        print_r($errors);
}
```

HTML Script

```
  <form method="post" action="index.php" name="signin-form">
      <table border="1">

                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td><td><input type="text" name="input-username" id="input-username"></td>
                    <td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="input-password" id="input-password"></td>

                    <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="sign-in" id="sign-in" value="Log in">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                     <td colspan="2">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me">
                     <label id="information">Keep Me Eating Picture</label>
                     </td>
                     <td colspan="2">
                     <a href="#" id="forgotpass">Forgotten My Username or Password</a>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
     </table>
 </form>
```

but somehow the condition is getting weird
after i input the username and password why that i should click the submit button twice in the log in content to redirect to logged in content?

like this: username obink password obink and enter

**first log in** is nothing happened but the username field and password field are empty
**the second log in** with the blank fields of username and password is the time to redirect the log in content to the logged in content

is it my code is going wrong or what? i had trying to rebuild the css but there is nothing happened. And ow ya, i have users function page already, it is the page which is storing any function what i need

here is the headers content design more or less:

div logo

div search box

and div user log in or not like this

```
        if (logged_in($user_data['user_id']) === false){
        include 'login.php';
        }
    else{
        include 'logged_in.php';
        }
```

all is float left

and the php in the user functions

```
function logged_in(){
return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
    }
```

in my source.php page

```
    if(logged_in() === true)
{$sid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_data = user_data($_SESSION['user_id'], 'user_id', 'username', 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email');
}
```

renew the condition on my headers
html on headers

```
    <div id="header">
    <div id="header-content">
<div id="logo">
<a href="index.php" style="text-decoration:none;">
          logo</a>
</div>

<div id="searchbox">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" size="50">
</div>
```

php on the middle of headers

```
if(empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
include 'includes/widgets/login.php';
}

else{
    include 'includes/widgets/loggedin.php';
    }
```

closing div

```
</div>
</div>
```

sorry for my English

Comment: You are not redirecting to the logged in content. After setting session, you are just printing errors if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
?>
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="signin-form">
      <table border="1">

                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td><td><input type="text" name="input-username" id="input-username"></td>
                    <td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="input-password" id="input-password"></td>

                    <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="sign-in" id="sign-in" value="Log in">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                     <td colspan="2">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me">
                     <label id="information">Keep Me Eating Picture</label>
                     </td>
                     <td colspan="2">
                     <a href="#" id="forgotpass">Forgotten My Username or Password</a>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
     </table>
 </form>
<?php
} else {
 echo "Logged in! <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
 //You can display the users name here; Example: echo "Hi, ".$user_data['name'];
}
?>
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST) === false){
$username = $_POST['input-username'];
$password = $_POST['input-password'];

    if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) ===true){
        $errors[] = 'You Need To Enter a Username And a Password';
        }
        else if(user_exists($username) === false){
        $errors[] = 'We Can\'t Find That Username';
            }

        else{
            $login = login($username, $password);

                if($login === false){
                    $errors[] = 'Your Username and Password Combination is Incorrect';
                    }
                else{
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
                    header("Location: index.php");
                    }
            }
        print_r($errors);
}
?>
```

*This will solve your login problem*

Comment: what is the different?
ow ya i stored my session on the different page so i just including it

Comment: i have this one in the users function

function logged_in(){
 return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
  }

and after that
in the headers


div logo

div searchbox

and 

div php filled by choice
if (logged_in($user_data['user_id']) === false){
include 'login.php';
}
else{
include 'logged_in.php';
}

Comment: I made an edit of the code. I added extra PHP code... Now you don't need to login twice

Comment: aye i have tried that way

but the only shows up is this things

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\bacon\new_web\all_links.php:30) in C:\xampp\htdocs\bacon\new_web\includes\widgets\login.php on line 21
Array ( )

Comment: and after that shows up i should log in again without fill anything on the username and password fields..

Comment: This forum will helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793482/php-error-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent

Comment: WHAT a gun!!!!
i just wrong wrote ob_start();
what i wrote was an ob_flush();
thx buddy
:D